# Limiting an encoded string to a specific number of characters

Tags: php, encryption

I want to encode a string of text in PHP but with a limit (characters) in the result.

E.g I want to encode the string "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" but I want the encoded result to only have 10 characters.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by encoding?

Comment: Do you need to be able to decode it?

Comment: @MathieuImbert I haven't tried much as I don't know where to start. I have a basic encrypting function using base64_encode() but I get a variable number of characters returned.

Comment: @NicholasPickering I will need to be able to decode it.

Comment: What are you trying todo? You cant compress and encrypt a string that long into 10 chars and reverse it back into your orig string. are you looking to encrypt it or hash it(one-way)?